# Intersect the contour and polygon in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, intersection, contour, clip

I have been trying for a few days to create the contour and then plot the shapefile and contour on the same file. Now, that I am able to create the contour and shapefile on the same plot. I want to clip the contour with the shapefile an only show the shapefile.

The data temp.csv can be found on this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/mg2bo4rcr6n3dks/temp.csv
Shapefile can be found on the following location: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ztvmibsslr9ocmc/YOtiwB8p9p

The script file image.scale.R can be found on the following location "https://www.dropbox.com/s/2f5s7cc02fpozk7/image.scale.R "

The code that I have used so far is as follows:

```
## Required packages 
library(maptools) 
library(rgdal) 
library(sp) 
library(maptools) 
library(sm) 
require(akima) 
require(spplot) 
library(raster) 
library(rgeos)

## Set Working Directory 
setwd("C:\\Users\\jdbaba\\Documents\\R working folder\\shape")

## Read Data from a file 
age2100 <- read.table("temp.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")

x <- age2100$x 
y <- age2100$y   
z <- age2100$z

####################################
##Load the shape file 
##################################### 
shapefile <- readShapePoly("Export_Output_4.shp")

fld <- interp(x,y,z)

par(mar=c(5,5,1,1)) filled.contour(fld)

###Import the image.scale 
source source("image.scale.R")
```

# http://menugget.blogspot.de/2011/08/adding-scale-to-image-plot.html

```
x11(width=8, height=7) 
layout(matrix(c(1,2), nrow=1, ncol=2), widths=c(6,1), height=6, respect=TRUE) 
layout.show(2)

par(mar=c(4,4,1,2)) 
image(fld,axes=T) 
contour(fld, add=TRUE)
#points(age2100$x,age2100$y, pch=".", cex=2,legend=F) 
plot(shapefile,add=T,lwd=2) 
box()
par(mar=c(4,0,1,4)) 
image.scale(fld, xlab="Eastings", ylab="Northings", xaxt="n", yaxt="n", horiz=FALSE)

axis(4)
mtext("Salinity", side=4, line=2.5)
```

The output of the above code is as follows:

[image]

Now, I want to get rid of the colored gradients and the contours from the polygon shapefile and only leave the intersection part.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Research: I found this link https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25112/clip-depth-contour-with-spatial-polygon on Stack exchange Gis and I tried to follow this method I always get error while creating the contour.

I found another similar thread on https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2009-May/005793.html . But I couldn't make it work on my dataset.

I would like to acknowledge Marc in the box for helping me in getting to this point.

Thanks.

Comment: Paul Murrell has an example in the latest R-journal (fig 14): http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2012-2/RJournal_2012-2_Murrell2.pdf

Comment: I am still unable to find this. Can anyone help please ???/////

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, @baptiste gave you a strong hint for the solution, the [recent paper by Paul Murrell](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2012-2/RJournal_2012-2_Murrell2.pdf). Paul was generous to provide us with the code for his entire paper manuscript, which you can get from [his personal website](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/). On the side topic, Paul shows beautiful example of reproducible research with this paper. Generally, I took the following approach:

- extract latitude and longitude coordinates from the shapefile (a function to do this is [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2010-June/008500.html), by Paul Hiemstra),
- plot everything with your code,
- and use `polypath` to remove everything outside the boundaries defined by shapefile, using extracted coordinates as a baseline.

  ```
  #function to extract coordinates from shapefile (by Paul Hiemstra)
  allcoordinates_lapply = function(x) { 
      polys = x@polygons 
      return(do.call("rbind", lapply(polys, function(pp) { 
             do.call("rbind", lapply(pp@Polygons, coordinates)) 
             }))) 
  } 
  q = allcoordinates_lapply(shapefile)

  #extract subset of coordinates, otherwise strange line connections occur...
  lat = q[110:600,1]
  long = q[110:600,2]

  #define ranges for polypath
  xrange <- range(lat, na.rm=TRUE)
  yrange <- range(long, na.rm=TRUE)
  xbox <- xrange + c(-20000, 20000)
  ybox <- yrange + c(-20000, 20000)

  #plot your stuff
  plot(shapefile, lwd=2)
  image(fld, axes=F, add=T)
  contour(fld, add=T)
  #and here is the magic 
  polypath(c(lat, NA, c(xbox, rev(xbox))),
           c(long, NA, rep(ybox, each=2)),
           col="white", rule="evenodd")
  ```

[image]

Comment: @ Geek On Acid, Thank you so much for this solution. I would check out Paul's code so that I could learn a bit more. Thanks again.